# Cannot create connection to Google Cloud SQL database

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I'm having trouble getting my with my database connection from my app engine instance to my cloud sql database. For whatever reason, this code has only recently stopped working. This code essentially never returns anything after `DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);` is called and causes the stacktrace included.

**Problem code:**

```
public static Connection createConnection(){
        String url = null;
        String user = ******;
        String password = ******;
        try {
            if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
                    SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");


url = "jdbc:google:mysql://{project_id}:{instance}/{db_name}";
            } else {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                url = "jdbc:mysql://{my_ip}:3306/{db_name}";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            return conn;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Stacktrace**

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.book.system.spi.BookForSaleV1.list(BookForSaleV1.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: The exception log shows that the exception is at "com.book.system.spi.BookForSaleV1.list(BookForSaleV1.java:77)". Additionally, when you say that the getConnection(...) call does not return anything, what do you mean ? Do you get null or do you go into the Exception block ?

Comment: It literally just never returned anything.

Comment: I just figure out however that if I include the password, it won't work.Removing the password and just using the username fixed the error. Apparently when calling from an authenticated app engine instance the password makes it fail.

Comment: The connections from App Engine come with a host=localhost. Check to see if you have setup a password for that account (`SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user` can show you that).